# If $f$ is nonnegative and integrable then $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically the Lebesgue integral of nonnegative functions, and need help with the following problem.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ be measurable and $f\in L^1$. Show that $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f$ is continuous.

I know is isn't much but the only thing a could think of is that given $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$ we note that $F(x) \leq F(y)$, i.e. $F$ is increasing. So maybe we can apply one of the convergence theorems of Lebesgue integration theory.

---

I was also wondering if this problem can be solved using only Riemann integration theory.

Comment: You can't solve this problem using only Riemann integration theory because Riemann integration does not know the concept of measurable functions. - But the analogous statement for Riemann integration is certainly also true (and possibly easier to prove)

Comment: No, you can't do it with just Riemann integration; the Riemann integral counterpart is true, but this is about Lebesgue integrable functions which include non-Riemann integrable functions. However, thinking about the Riemann case is helpful. Specifically, in the Riemann case the proof turns out to be easy because Riemann integrable functions are bounded. If you could approximate your $f$ by a bounded function then the situation would be easy. Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. 
It suffices to prove that $F(x_n) \to F(x)$ for every $x_n \to x$.
Therefore, let $x_n \to x$.

We have $F(x_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f \cdot \chi_{[-\infty,x_n]} $.

It is easy to see that $f \cdot \chi_{[-\infty,x_n]} \to f \cdot \chi_{[-\infty,x]}$ (except possibly at $x$).

$f \cdot \chi_{[-\infty,x_n]}$ is dominated by an integrable function (namely, $f$). Therefore, we have $F(x_n) \to F(x)$.

Comment: alternatively, one can show that $F$ is both right and left continuous separately. For instance, taking a decreasing sequence $x_{n}$ to $x$ and use MCT theorem to show that $F$ is right continuous.

Answer (score 1):

For $x<y$ since integration (in any reasonable type of integration) is additive on union of disjoint sets,

$$ F(x) + \int_{x}^y f=\int_{(-\infty,x)} f + \int_{(x,y)} f =\int_{(-\infty,x) \cup (x,y)}  f=F(y)$$
$$\implies F(y)-F(x)=\int_{x}^y f$$
$$\implies |F(y)-F(x)|=|\int_{x}^y f| \leq \int_{x}^y |f|$$

LEMMA (A Key lemma, very basic and crucial.): If $f$ is integrable, i.e. in $L^1$, for any $\epsilon >o$ given, there is a $\delta >0$, such that
$$ \forall A, \ \ \ \  |A|<\delta \implies \int_{A} |f| < \epsilon.$$

The important thing is that we don't care what set, and where, $A$ is!

In light of this lemma, if $x$ is $\delta$-close to $y$, we'll have

$$|F(y)-F(x)| < \epsilon .$$

So, we even proved more: $F(x)$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. same $\delta$ works for all points in the definition of continuity.